# Definition of attractor of dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition, dynamical-systems

This is a question on a definition of attractor of a dynamical system.

Consider a dynamical system $\phi(t,x)$ satisfying

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}\phi(t,x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
+1 & \text{if } x > 0 \\
\end{cases} $$

Hence $x=-1$ and $+1$ are stable fixed points, with basin of attraction $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ respectively, and $x=0$ is an unstable fixed points.

We have the following definitions:

1. a closed invariant set $A\subset\mathbb R$ is an *attracting set* if there is an open neighborhood $U\supseteq A$ such that $\forall x\in U$ we have $\phi_t(x)\in U$ for all $t\geq 0$ and $\phi_t(x)\to A$ as $t\to \infty$.
2. An *attractor* is an attracting set which contains a dense orbit.

My question is whether the set $[-1,1]$ is an attractor? Clearly it is an attracting set because every initial condition in $\mathbb R$ will converge inside $[-1,1]$. But this is not an attractor, beacuse we can split into two disjoint basins of attraction, namely $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$. I would claim that the only attractors of this system are $\{-1\}$ and $\{1\}$.

However based on our definition, it seems that $[-1,1]$ *is* an attractor because it contains a dense orbit. Of course, take any orbit like $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\phi(t,x_0)$ accumulates at $x=1$, hence it is dense. So how can my book claim that $[-1,1]$ does not contain any dense orbit? Besides, how could the subset $(0,1]$ contain a dense orbit and $[-1,1]$ not contain a dense orbit, when $(0,1]\subseteq[-1,1]$? Some clarification would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it contains no dense orbit. Dense means that it gets arbitrarily close to any point in in the interval. But in your case any orbit has a single limit point (converges).

Comment: @JohnB Yes, I misunderstood. A more full definition would be that an interval $I$ contains a dense orbit if there exists a point $x_0\in I$ such that the trajectory $x(t)$ becomes arbitrarily close to every point in $I$. But how about the set $[\frac{1}{2},1]$? An orbit started at $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ seems to be dense, but I would not call this interval an attractor.